# Select nested elements by class

Tags: excel, vba, select, web-scraping, nested

I'm working on a macro to analyse one certain website and I'm trying to select nested elements by class. The html code is as follows:

```
<div class="publication_info">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="first">A</th>
    <th class="second">B</th>
    <th class="third">C</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the content of the cell with the class "third" (which would be the letter C). My approach is to first select the table by the class "publication_info" and afterwards the cell by the class "third", but it doesn't work. My code is:

```
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set html = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

With html
    Set oInfos = .getElementsByClassName("publication_info")(0).getElementsByClassName("third")(0)
End With
```

Strangely enough, the table can be accessed easily.

Any ideas? Your help is much appreciated!
Best regards

Comment: Try this `Dim oInfos As HTMLDivElement` first and then do what you tried to.

Comment: I am also looking for solution of this issue. let me know if you find any solution or alternative for this.
(MSXML is not selecting class under class.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can scrape the table, but not its content, then I assume that the content is dynamically reloaded. In this case you have to work with Internet Explorer. MSXML2.XMLHTTP cannot handle dynamic content, it only fetches the first static part of a page.

Try it like this:

```
Sub TestForThird()

Dim url As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim nodeTable As Object
Dim nodeThird As Object

  url = "Here your URL"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer and load page
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.navigate url
  Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.readyState = 4

  'Wait to load dynamic content to the table
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))

  'Get table
  Set nodeTable = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("publication_info")(0)

  'Get third from table
  Set nodeThird = nodeTable.getElementsByClassName("third")(0)

  'Show innertext
  mesgbox nodeThird.innertext
End Sub
```